# GitLab CE on Kubernetes - error executing run on gitlab/ssh

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm pulling my hair attempting to fix this error when installing GitLab CE through Helm on Kubernetes (`helm install --namespace gitlab-ce --values gitlab-ce-values.yml --name gitlab-ce --set externalUrl=http://gitlab.local/ stable/gitlab-ce`

`Error executing action 'run' on resource 'ruby_block[directory resource: /gitlab-data/ssh]'`

I have found one reply [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1601) with the following reply DJ Mountney:

> one of your directories in /home/share/projects/repos is likely missing the execute bit for everyone. that means, that even though git owns /home/share/projects/repos it can't easily get there due to parent permissions.
>   You likely have to run a sudo chmod +x on /home/share (assuming that's the directory missing the execute flag)

This seemed to solve that person's issue, however, I have the correct flags set all the way from root, so this is not my issue.

I don't even know where to start. I've been at this for twelve hours and have gotten absolutely nowhere.

Can someone help me to proceed with installing GitLab on Docker (Kubernetes)?

**UPDATE**:I believe I've found a hint toward the issue. I was running Minikube through Virtualbox, which doesn't support advanced features on its mounted (shared) folders.

I have been trying to instead run minikube using `xhyve`, but now I can't access the Internet as Virtualbox has handled this previously. I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://github.com/surajnarwade/opencompose-examples/tree/master/output-gitlab to get gitlab on kubernetes, I hope, that will help you.